# How can I show the Org-mode agenda on Emacs start-up?

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs, org-mode

I would like the Org-mode agenda to automatically show what I have to do today when I open Emacs. The org-agenda command is interactive, so it doesn't seem to work well for this purpose.

Is there a way to show the Org-mode agenda on Emacs start-up?

Thanks,

Conor

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `after-init-hook` to run a piece of code after initialization has finished. To run `(org-agenda-list)` after init, use:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'org-agenda-list)
```

Comment: That's the ticket. kwatford's answer below was also very helpful, but I couldn't add '(org-agenda-list 1) as the argument for my .emacs file. If someone could clear this up, I'd be delighted.

Comment: `(add-hook 'after-init-hook '(lambda () (org-agenda-list 1)))`

Comment: This works but how can I focus on the "Org Agenda" buffer on startup? (I'm using tabbar)

Comment: OK, I figured that out.  Adding an answer.

Comment: To make this work with emacsclient you can use a focus-in-hook instead of the after-init-hook. In order to show your agenda items you should set your agenda-file/directory before setting the hook,   (setq org-agenda-files (quote ("agenda-directory")))

Comment: The `server-after-make-frame-hook` works perfectly if you use `emacsclient`.

Answer (score 10):

This works for me (in `.emacs`):

```
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
(org-agenda-list)
(delete-other-windows)
```

Without the first line, the splash screen "covered" the agenda; without the third one, the scratch buffer remained visible.

Comment: For emacsclient, we can use `emacsclient -t --eval "(org-agenda-list)" "(delete-other-windows)"` Make it as `function` or `alias`.

Comment: This would limit other usages of the editor wouldn't it, what happens if you ask emacs to open with a file?

Answer (score 5):

One alternative to the hook is to set the `initial-buffer-choice` variable.  This is particularly useful if there are multiple buffers or a number of functions on the hook.  The function on this variable needs to return a buffer.  Naively this might be:

```
(setq initial-buffer-choice (lambda ()
    (org-agenda-list 1)
    (get-buffer "*Org Agenda*")))
```

Comment: this one still shows the scratch buffer. (emacs 26.1)

Comment: @krokodil isn't this desirable.  Then emacs will behave well when presented with other arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Try `(org-agenda-list)`. If you just want today, `(org-agenda-list 1)`.

And of course, apropos is your friend. `C-h C-a org-agenda` (or whatever command) will show you useful info on that command.

Answer (score 2):

I have a bash alias to start emacs with the Agenda open:

`alias org='/usr/bin/emacs --funcall org-agenda-list &'`

Enjoy.

Comment: This is the best answer to get emacsclient working with agenda view in emacs 30:
Ubunt startup applications: run daemon in 'Startup Applications Pref as this: `/usr/bin/emacs-snapshot -daemon --funcall org-agenda-list &` then

Set a hot key (Win + G): `emacsclient-snapshot -c -n --eval '(org-agenda-list)'`

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly at startup, but I keep Emacs running so I need a different approach

```
(require 'midnight)
(midnight-delay-set 'midnight-delay "7:30am")
(add-hook 'midnight-hook 'org-agenda-list)
```

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14947354/217408

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `server-after-make-frame-hook` to run any command when the emacs daemon creates a client-

```
(use-hook 'server-after-make-frame-hook 'org-agenda-list)
```

This works perfectly for me because whenever I open emacsclient, org agenda appears which is exactly what I wanted.

You can also look at the following hooks if they suit your needs more-
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Hooks.html

Comment: It throws an error using the emacs 30.0.50 version; any update on how to make agenda view appear on startup using the emacslient?

Comment: Can you mention the error you were getting?