# How to periodically run a task within emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a way to periodically run an elisp function in a long-running emacs, similar to cron, but within the emacs process?

For example I want to "automatically run (recentf-save-list) every half hour" because it otherwise only runs on exit, which sucks when emacs occasionally crashes. (There are other examples as well so looking for a general solution rather than one in particular for recentf).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Check out [`run-with-timer`](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Idle-Timers.html).

```
(run-with-timer 0 (* 30 60) 'recentf-save-list)
```

Comment: That link is to the idle timers page (also useful of course).

Comment: @JSpen The question was to have something run every half hour, and the documentation for `run-with-timer` accepts a number in seconds, so `(* 30 60)` is just a way of denoting 30 minutes.  `(* 30 60)` is the lisp way of multiplying 30 and 60.

Comment: @TreyJackson - I salute you. You are helpful and patient.

Answer (score 4):

You might also find [midnight mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MidnightMode) useful. One can arbitrarily define 'midnight' and then add hooks as desired.