# How can I run a function periodically in a specific mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am writing a report in LaTeX, and am using Emacs for development. Having to periodically compile manually is somewhat annoying. Is there a way to have Emacs automatically compile periodically whenever the current buffer is a LaTeX buffer?

Comment: How about `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () . . . ))` and `run-with-timer` ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841459/how-to-periodically-run-a-task-within-emacs

Comment: Or, how about an option specific to LaTeX -- e.g., `-pvc` via the command line, or `$preview_continuous_mode` within a `latexmkrc` file?  I would imagine that AUCTeX also has those options.

Comment: you could check out the flymake package as well.

Answer (score 2):

[`flymake`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlyMake) is built into Emacs, and is the classic way to do such things.
See its user-manual at: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(flymake)` <kbd>RET</kbd>

[`flycheck`](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck) is a more recent project, with the stated aim of being "flymake done right".

Running arbitrary processes (e.g. compilation) periodically is what these libraries are all about, so either one of them suits your use-case.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I stumbled on this recently, and tried to make this work. I however couldn't figure out how to run a custom function using flymake/flycheck from the documentation. Can you please help?

Comment: There's an example for flymake in the manual at `C-h i g (flymake)An annotated example backend`.  I don't use flycheck, and I don't make much use of flymake either, so that's all I can tell you offhand.