# Calling an org-mode custom command in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

Org-mode allow to define custom commands by customizing **org-agenda-custom-commands**. Doing something like this:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("pb" "Bugs "
      (
       (todo "KNOWNCAUSE")
       (todo "BUG")
       (todo "REPORT")
      )
    ((org-agenda-files (list projects-dir))))
```

will allow me to press *C-c a* to call the agenda dispatcher and then if i press *pb* it will filter my todos by folder (*project-dirs*) and by states.

Is there an elisp function that *calls* that (a specific) custom command defined in org-agenda-custom-commands directly?

Rephrasing: I would like an elisp function that if called shows my filtered todos, just like pressing *C-c a p b* now does.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you asking for a method of calling a particular agenda view at start-up? In which case this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010539/how-can-i-show-the-org-mode-agenda-on-emacs-start-up/32467530#32467530 answer may help.  Perhaps you could rephrase your question with the outcome you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I'm sorry if I was unclear, I've now expanded my question. I do not seek to open the agenda view at startup like is described in the answer you linked (my end goal is to open a specific filtered todos list at startup, but this is beyond the point of the question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are asking for a way to call through the dispatcher from a function so you can reuse your configured dispatcher.  Try:

```
(org-agenda nil "pb")
```

If you are looking for function to add to a hook or initialize you can wrap this up using a lambda expression. So for example you might have your inital-buffer as this view:

```
(setq initial-buffer-choice (lambda ()
  (org-agenda nil "pb")
  (get-buffer "*Org Agenda*")))
```

Comment: *(org-agenda nil "pb")* is what I was looking for! Thanks again for your time :)